# Install lxml without pip

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

**Objective -** 
To install lxml on the machine without pip

**Issue**
Due to my company firewall and lack of admin access, I am not able to use pip. It throws an error. Hence I am not able to install pip

**Steps taken till now**

On my development machine(windows 7), I dont have admin access hence I cannot use pip or easy_install. For BeuatifulSoup & requests, I downloaded the source and put the source in Python34 -> Lib folder. For lxml as well I have downloaded the source file and put it under Lib folder but I still get the same error.

Please note, I cannot ask for Admin access, because its my personal project and my organization will not provide admin access for personal project.

Hence, I want to know how can I install or use lxml on my system.

Comment: Both `pip` and `easy_install` allow you to install to non-standard (read: Non-admin locked) locations. The `--user` option is the simplest, but `--prefix` also works for installing to arbitrary location.

Answer (score 0):

lxml is at least partly coded in C, and putting C source in /Lib does not work, as you found.

If you are allowed, download a Windows installer and install for 'this user only'. It would probably work better to use 3.5.1, to avoid clashes with the already installed 3.4.  You could then use pip to install packages.